# Estou tentando acessar os valores de css dentro de uma variavel porem não estou conseguindo

Tags: react

Estou usando o código abaixo porem não consigo acessar os valores da variável `cssPrimary` e usar outros valores junto, alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda.

Preciso dessa ajudinha

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

let cssPrimary = {
background: '#192254',
color: '#FFFFFF',
stroke: '#FFFFFF',
justifyContent: 'space-between',
backgroundHover: '#24CCB8',
strokeHover: '#434343',
colorHover: '#434343',
}

console.log(Object.values(cssPrimary), 'teste');
const getStyle = (props) => {
  if (props.category === 'primary') {
    if (props.states === 'default' && props.sizes === 'large') { 
      return {
        cssPrimary,
        height: '200px',
      }
    }
```